# Can a typescript function return an object extended with another object whose functions `this` is the union of the original and extension?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make typescript understand a recursive `this` type? I want to type up some working JavaScript that allows extending a base object with extra functions. What I've got currently looks like this:

```
interface ThingBase {
  method(): string;
  data: string;
}

function makeThing<
  Ext extends {[index:string]: (this: ThingBase & Ext, ...args:any[]) => any}
>(extension: Ext): ThingBase & Ext {
  return {
    ...extension,
    method() { return "hello" },
    data: "yes"
  }
}

const thingWithExt = makeThing({
  yello: function() {
    return this.data; // works
  },
  mmm: function() {
    return this.yello(); // does not work
  }
});

const d = thingWithExt.yello();
```

But this doesn't work, it errors on the function names with `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'ThingBase'`

If I remove `& Ext` from the `this` type then it works in that the extension functions can access the base functions, but they cannot access other extension functions.

Here's a playground with a slightly modified version that TS accepts but still does not type correctly: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Please pick which of the two code blocks you want us to work with, either the one in the question or the one in the playground, and make sure the question and playground agree with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ThisType` to signal to TypeScript what `this` is supposed to be inside an object literal.

```
function makeThing<
    Ext extends Record<keyof Ext, (...a: any[]) => any>
>(extension: Ext & ThisType<Ext & ThingBase > ): ThingBase & Ext {
    return {
        ...extension,
        method() { return "hello" },
        data: "yes"
    }
}

const thingWithExt = makeThing({
    yello: function () {
        return this.data; // works
    },
    mmm: function () {
        return this.yello(); // also ok
    },
    te() {
        return this.mmm();
    }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMBCcDOKA3gLABQylyAthGOgPYAmAFAJQBcy+YU2A3OSrImcMHC48+ILILIBfcuRgBXEAjDAGIGnADWEDNgA8QqgFEAHmGQRrEEE3zIAShAQMoTYwYCeDGGQrMAAaZBYAOiiJZDgQXwBtAF02ZABeAD5Y+IzyDJY7SBB8LRAuYOQAMjRMfFRfAAcIYwrqoxk8QmQszhrsTpRqitIKKig6FSgdEeFhKIjChxLtELNZmjpGVlSiZHGwSZ0AInQIABszhiPkeVXR9dFxLiPfCHwjtZvyRTJyD2KbPRsAB1YD0CppXQGdpYFgzKivC4MLiqdSabThHafYT7Q7IIH4CKPOD8ZAAejJyAA7p49PhPrdPtRmSi1BpSpjkPD1ripvjahFEZd2KSKbEzvgGMgGHoGXdhJB2FzsWMJnyCRFmdQRQzvmw5H9tDwROl+SCwehgoLzsL9UA)